# grpc Python: ignore untrusted certificate

Tags: python, ssl, grpc

I want to create a grpc channel to a source that I trust, but whose certificate I lack.
Setting up a secure channel with default credentials fails:

```
import gprc
ssh_channel = grpc.secure_channel(<gprc url>, grpc.ssl_channel_credentials())
grpc.channel_ready_future(ssh_channel).result()
```

Results in:

```
E1017 10:05:15.783011100   11539 ssl_transport_security.cc:1229] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
E1017 10:05:16.846366639   11539 ssl_transport_security.cc:1229] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
E1017 10:05:18.688887874   11539 ssl_transport_security.cc:1229] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
E1017 10:05:21.557399186   11539 ssl_transport_security.cc:1229] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
```

I know this is possible, since e.g. in Java one would do the following:

```
import io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts;
import io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.util.InsecureTrustManagerFactory;
...
sslContext = GrpcSslContexts.forClient().trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build();
channel = NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(<gprc url>, 443).sslContext(sslContext).build();
```

However I haven't found any similar way for Python.
The documentation of `grpc.secure_channel` also describes an `option` argument, that according to the documentation is:

> An optional list of key-value pairs (channel args in gRPC Core runtime) to configure the channel.

A reference to channel args [here](https://grpc.io/grpc/cpp/group__grpc__arg__keys.html) does not provide any help either. Any ideas?

**UPDATE: (19/01/14):**

There is an open pull request to add this option in the Python code, but it seems stuck in a PR for months now: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/12656

Answer (score 6):

You may have to fetch the certificate from the site in a separate step. If it can be a one-off, just use your browser and save the cert somewhere convenient. Otherwise, see [How can I retrieve the TLS/SSL peer certificate of a remote host using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689941/how-can-i-retrieve-the-tls-ssl-peer-certificate-of-a-remote-host-using-python).

In my case I saved the cert with my browser and did the following (I needed to override the target name with the one in the cert as it was self-signed and the domain name didn't match):

```
with open(cert_path, 'rb') as f:
    cert_bytes = f.read()

credentials = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(cert_bytes)
# Deal with cert being self-signed:
cert_cn = "cn.from.cert.com" # or parse it out of the cert data
options = (('grpc.ssl_target_name_override', cert_cn,),)

channnel = grpc.secure_channel(target, credentials, options)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, as the network contains a proxy server with a different domain name. I would rather prefer an option that allows ignoring ssl certificate just as is possible in Java.

Comment: Hi. Have you found solution you wanted?